# Load images in viewpager from MySQL database

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hello I have made an application and have a viewpager there for image sliding so I want to know how to load images in viewpager from Remote server thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Picasso library. Into your adapter use `Picasso.with(activity).load("your image url").into(your_image_view)`
More information about Picasso here [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy but will it help me in sliding the image because what I want to build is a image slider where user can slide the image one after another  so please inform if there is any other libraries for this thing

Comment: @vipssingh if you don't want to make your custom slider with Viewpager , you can use this library. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: Thanks mate looking to the answer will ask if there is any problem occurs